# Acer swift 3: microphone not working with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound, acer, microphone

I installed Ubuntu on my new laptop, quite a challenge as I am not well versed in computing. It seems to be working fine, except the inbuilt microphone is not working. Not too sure what to do about it, am I missing a driver?

Here is the screen grab from alsamixer:

[image: screenshot]

I do not see a microphone

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Press `F4` key to see the Capture/Input controls. But you probably won't see them. Not yet.

Remember those "HDA Intel" and "ALC256". They will be important in your quest for answers.
You are not alone, check this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1793410
**This last post resumes it all:**
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=279424&start=47
Check preceding posts above for more details...

This kind of problem is usually solved by adding an option line at the end of `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` **file**. You will need to **restart** your computer to see the result. You could try adding `options snd-hda-intel model=headset-mic` at the end of `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` **file**. Or something else. There are lots of things to be tried with this file. **Restart** your computer for each test. You need to open the file as administrator to be able to make changes. Check my tutorial for more details:
[Asus Eee Pc X101ch and Intel Atom: Fix The Speaker And Microphone!](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=264417)
You probably won't find the exact answer there but you can follow the method...

Did you find the right answer? Please share with us! But seemingly... there is no solution yet. Bonne chance!

Answer (score 2):

This bug has been addressed here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201251

The safe workaround for now is by changing the model of your `snd-hda-intel` to `dell-headset-multi`. But with this workaround, your notebook internal microphone is still unusable, only external microphone works.

1. Open `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` with your favorite editor with sudo privilege
2. Add `options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi` in the bottom
3. Save
4. If you want quick apply, execute `sudo alsa force-reload`, otherwise, reboot your notebook
5. insert your headset (headphone with microphone) to the audio slot, then audio mode selection popup will show, select `Headset` mode (an icon with headphone and microphone)

Answer (score 1):

Edit the file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Add the following line:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=,dell-headset-multi
```

*(Note: The comma is required.)*

Save the file with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, and exit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.

Then restart the computer.  (`force-reload` doesn't work)

This works for me on Ubuntu 18.04 with ASUS T300

Comment: Now everytime it pops up a window asking me to chhose 1. Headphone, 2. Headset. How do I make it automatic.

Comment: For me the comma didn't work. Maybe it works with ASUS but not with Swift 3.