# Microphone not working Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: sound, alsa, 19.10, microphone, realtek

I have an Acer Swift 3 SF314-56 with Ubuntu 19.10 installed (the card is a Realtek ALC256).

My microphone does not work.
I've tried lot of thing such as put the line "options snd-hda-intel model=acer-headset-multi" at the botton of the file "/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf". I've also installed HDAJackRetask and connected pin 012 and 013 to internal mic and bot ovveride. I've set Mic_Boost on alsamixer equal to zero.

[image]

Well, nothing worked. The mic is now not dectected at all.
Could someone help me?

I missed an infornation. Ubuntu is installed in dual boot alongside windows 10 (which I use rarely). On windows the microphone is detected and works well.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 is going to reach end of life on 17th July 2020. I would suggest to move to 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 2):

I have been struggling through this issue for months. Apparently this is a recognized issue with devices using the Realtek ALC256 card (which includes the Acer Swift 3). There is a long thread on something similar on [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201251).

I finally stumbled across a workaround to enable use of headset mics here: [acer swift 3: microphone not working with ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/1167720/669558), to add `options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi` to the `alsa-base.conf`. You can follow the steps mentioned there (I did however have to restart my computer as `alsa force-reload` did not do the trick for me). This worked for me on Acer Swift 3 and Ubuntu 20

Please note however, the onboard mic will still not work.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: Kernels 5.14-rc5 onwards, 5.13.10 onwards, 5.10.58 onwards have the following fix already applied, enjoy :D**

So! Just made my headset microphone work on my Acer SF314-56 on Ubuntu 21.04. Happy happy happy :)

Looks like when you are using SOF driver the `options snd-hda-intel ...` over at `/etc/modprobe.d/*` have no effect. Thus (from my understanding) why HDAJackRetask won't help.

Also! Checkout this out! [As 5.14-rc1 there is no patch for our lovely SF314-56..](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e73f0f0ee7541171d89f2e2491130c7771ba58d3/sound/pci/hda/patch_realtek.c#L8276) hmmm...

So based on these findings here is the fix...

**For custom-kernel people**  that is easy: Just add the following line and compile.

`SND_PCI_QUIRK(0x1025, 0x1300, "Acer SWIFT SF314-56", ALC256_FIXUP_ACER_MIC_NO_PRESENCE),` over at `struct snd_pci_quirk alc269_fixup_tbl[]` at `sound/pci/hda/patch_realtek.c`. For the brave ones that don't know how-to compile a custom kernel but willing to [here is a cool guide](https://www.maketecheasier.com/build-custom-kernel-ubuntu/). If you are using secureboot then [you gotta also sign it](https://gloveboxes.github.io/Ubuntu-for-Azure-Developers/docs/signing-kernel-for-secure-boot.html). If you are using ZFS then iirc you also need zfs-dkms.

**For people who aren't willing to compile a custom-kernel nor have a time machine or just want to experiment fast on some other device**

Then you gotta disable SOF and rollback to legacy driver in order to make `options snd-hda-intel ...` have effect, however! this results with disabling DMIC. So add `options snd-intel-dspcfg dsp_driver=1` to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`.

Afterwards you gotta create a patch over at `/lib/firmware/`, lets name it `alc256-sound-patch.fw`. Based on [this documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.0/sound/hd-audio/notes.html#early-patching) and the observation over at `/sound/pci/hda/patch_realtek.c` that device `Acer TravelMate B311R-3` has the patch we need we paste the following code. If you are using some other device this is a place for some experimentation.

```
[codec]
0x10ec0256 0x10251300 0

[subsystem_id]
0x10251430
```

Finally enable the patch by also adding `options snd-hda-intel patch=alc256-sound-patch.fw` to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`. Then restart.

If you want also add `options snd-hda-codec dyndbg=+p` in order to have some more info over at dmesg.

If anyone know how to use `options snd-hda-intel` with SOF please let us know how-to!

Comment: @dotdeb pinging since we share the same problem

Comment: @jacques pinging since we share the same problem

Comment: @user2944562 pinging since we share the same problem

Comment: I thought that it would be cool to let you know that I found a fix for Ubuntu 21.04, since we all share the same problem as OP. I feel kinda jerk for pinging you like this but I think I did the right decision to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I am having exactly the same issue. The problem seems to be that the built-in microphones are not part of the Intel HDA, but are connected to another codec. Forcing Linux to enable the (unconnected) microphone input will only result in some
hum / system noise. I found more information here:

[Built-in mic recognized but not working (Mint 19.2 64 bit) - Linux Mint Forums](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=306080)

However, don't get your hopes up; as far as I could find, it has not been fixed yet.

Answer (score 0):

[new alsamixer display for acer swift3 SF314-56 (Kubuntu 20.04 LTS)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yerrT.png)

Same Acer swift3 SF314-56 running Kubuntu 19.10 mic didn't work neither. Then updated to kubuntu 20.04 LTS, and after a recent kernel update (I have now a kernel 5.4.0-52-generic), the internal mic started to work with an updated kde sound control applet. Actually that corresponds to a linux kernel switch to SOF (Sound Open Firmware) infrastructure for intel audio. The intel HDA (with underlying Realtek ACL256 for our Acer swift 3 SF314-56) works fine now with new HDMI ouptuts controls (tested on my TV), and 2 new controls for mics (internal digital mic and headphone mic). But I still have an issue for headphone mic.
Here an extract of kernel boot that explains the new module mapping :

```
dmesg | grep snd
[    5.345758] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
[    5.345974] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Digital mics found on Skylake+ platform, using SOF driver
[    5.873767] snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0: autoconfig for ALC256: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    5.873768] snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    5.873769] snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    5.873770] snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    5.873770] snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0:    inputs:
[    6.136530] snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0: ASoC: sink widget AIF1TX overwritten
[    6.136534] snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0: ASoC: source widget AIF1RX overwritten
[    6.136629] skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: snd-soc-dummy-dai <-> DMIC48kHz 6 mapping ok
[    6.136644] skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: snd-soc-dummy-dai <-> DMIC16kHz 7 mapping ok
[    6.136665] skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: snd-soc-dummy-dai <-> HDA Analog 0 mapping ok
[    6.136684] skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: snd-soc-dummy-dai <-> HDA Digital 1 mapping ok
[    6.136701] skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: snd-soc-dummy-dai <-> HDMI1 3 mapping ok
[    6.136714] skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: snd-soc-dummy-dai <-> HDMI2 4 mapping ok
[    6.136729] skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: snd-soc-dummy-dai <-> HDMI3 5 mapping ok
```

The linux kernel bug resolution history for DMIC on intel HDA is there :
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201251#c116

Comment: edited with some technical clues

Comment: I can't tell exactly when Ubuntu made the update (probably a kernel backport, or sof firmware update), but pretty sure it is recent as some comment in history prove that other people requested an ubuntu 20.04 (like comment #185 or #191 in kernel bug history).

Comment: this thread can also give you details about related needed audio package update (you will see several kernel test as well as ubuntu 20.04 tests) : https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=318670

Comment: last comment, to see mic (captures page) you need to change display in alsamixer (so f4 or f5)

Comment: there was a dkms packaging update for alsa sof-dvpt for kernel 5.4, 3 monthes ago, plus a quite recent linux firmware update (for sound as well), so I guess this is what activated  the succesfull update of our acer swift 3 module in 20.04 kernel (see hui wang activity).

Comment: tested this : "options snd-hda-intel model=alc255-acer,dell-headset-multi" didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

@pedro-siqueira's answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1307107/1133973 perfectly solves this issue without any further side effects **On ALC255**

Solution :

add

```
options snd-hda-intel model=alc255-acer,dell-headset-multi
```

to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

and reboot.

Should work smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution out, on a similar question: https://askubuntu.com/a/1406919/1593265
There is a video tutorial included in it too if you want to see the whole process and results beforehand.