# Headset microphone not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: pulseaudio, headphones, microphone, headset, pavucontrol

When I'm speaking with my internal microphone and I connect my headset, it's not detecting the microphone on it. Thing that does not happen in Windows, also didn't happen in Ubuntu 18.04

Any suggestion to fix it?

Comment: I seem to be able to detect the headset mic into "pavucontrol". I see sound captured, but the device is shown as "Headset Stereo Microphone (unplugged)". This device do not appear in the sounds parameter, but only in pavucontrol. That's a first step but I don't know how to fix from there. This answer sounds interesting: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243768/ubuntu-20-04-lenovo-ideapad-microphone-not-working

Comment: I've found a ticket in PulseAudio tracker with a similar behaviour: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/issues/941

Comment: @EricBurel You should have started your own question and ran the bounty from there. It is hard to help if we cannot see output from your machine.. Try unplugging /replugging 10 /15 times and see if any of them give a different result. What does the command `pactl list sources` give?

Comment: Ah sorry, that's because it's most probably the same bug under the hood that I encounter and some answers are just palliatives to an underlying bug.

Comment: any chance that this question will be solved? I have the same problem with Asus ux501 and it looks like I'm not the only one with this problem.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

So, trying various stuff I am not sure which step was effective. Ubuntu 20.0.4 using Cinnamon (no Gnome/KDE) on Dell XPS 9340:

1. `rm -rf ~/.config/pulse/`
2. Log out
3. Log back in
4. go to desktop settings/'sound'
5. insert headphones
6. Go to 'input' section
7. Do microphone audio test on each available device

Headphones start working...

Comment: worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 GNOME.

Comment: I confirm, this worked on Lubuntu 20.04

Comment: This worked for me on Kubuntu 20.10

Comment: This worked for me. But a safer thing to do will be to move it to another directory say you run `sudo mv pulse pulse_old` . Then you restart your machine. If everything works fine, you can delete that `pulse_old` directory.

Comment: while this may work, I don't want to log out every time my microphone isn't working.

Comment: This didn't work for my Sennheiser BT headset. However I was never able to use its mic yet.

Comment: For my BT headset problems, there is a bug (at some ubuntus/hardware fixed, at some not, as of Dec 7, 2020) referenced from https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265894/bluetooth-headset-problem-ubuntu-20-04-intel-nuc10i5fnh4-when-switching-to-hs#comment2164559_1265894

Comment: This doesn't work for me my laptop model is asuspro

Comment: not working for me on Ubuntu 20.10 :( `$ cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ALC295
Codec: Intel Icelake HDMI` any hints what could I try? It is not working neither in USB live session... I've unresolved Q here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305942/external-headset-microphone-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-10-not-even-wired-cable-h

Comment: This is not working on Ubuntu 18.04. The Sound settings is detecting my  headphone but Chrome cannot. It does not allow me to use my microphone on  Google Meet or any other website despite me giving it access to.

Comment: @bmaupin Shouldn't be necessary to log out, actually. If you rename the pulse directory, it'll be recreated when you open an app like OBS Studio.

Comment: `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload` would also do instead of log in & log out.

Comment: Not working in Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Not working for me :/ headset mic is working fine on my laptop with Ubuntu 20, but not my tower

Comment: worked on msi laptop

Comment: It did not work for me on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 30):

So after having this issue with beautiful, but already annoying, 20.04, I found a solution in another post at SuperUser. In my case what helped me was:

1. Use the following command to get the Audio Codec for your machine's model:

   ```
   cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec
   ```

   In my case I saw the following audio and video codecs:

   ```
   Codec: Realtek ALC233
   Codec: Nvidia GPU 94 HDMI/DP
   ```
2. Go to [www.kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/hd-audio/models.html), look up the version of the codec, and get the full name of it. In my case, for `Realtek ALC233` it's `alc233-eapd`.
3. Create/update the `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` file, and add this line, replacing the model with your own:

   ```
   options snd-hda-intel model=alc233-eapd
   ```
4. Reboot the machine.

Comment: Wait, what exactly am I looking up on kernel.org? My codec is "Realtek ALC298", what am I looking for and where?

Comment: In the case of 'Realtek ALC298', it seems that the codec would be either `alc298-dell1`, or `alc298-dell-aio`. Just do a global search on that page for 'Realtek ALC298', and you'll see.

Comment: Mine is ALC289, and there is no one in kernel.org with this model. I'm trying the closest one, to see if it works. will keep you updated. Thank you!

Comment: I really want to upvote this answer; now every time I plug in my headset I get a popup asking me to choose headphones or headset as a source, but clicking Headset doesn't actually set my input device and I still have to do it manually: https://askubuntu.com/q/1294950/18665

Comment: @Kostanos there is one. It has `ALC28x` for  your codec, look up `ALC22x/23x/25x/269/27x/28x/29x`.

Comment: not working for Ubuntu 20.10 with Realtek ALC295 on ACER SPIN 5 :(

Comment: https://www.thomasventurini.com/articles/fix-missing-audio-input-device-in-ubuntu/

Comment: You saved me :)) Thanks.

Comment: Not working for me either with Realtek ALC233

Comment: @YuriiS This worked for me. I don't understand why this configuration needs to be added though. If the proper codec is in /proc/asound/card*/codec*, doesn't it mean that the kernel properly recognized the device?

Answer (score 14):

What fixed this for me was running `pulseaudio -k` in Terminal.

Comment: The same, on Zorin OS (based on ubuntu 20.4)

Comment: After this command, it started to showing new audio profile HSP/HFP against headset, i choose it instead of high fidelity playback (A2DP Sink)

Answer (score 4):

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on my Sony Vaio VPCEH28FN with intel-hda-sound card.
Output of `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec` is
Codec: Conexant CX20590
Codec: Nvidia GPU 1c HDMI/DP .

What worked for me was --

1. I did `sudo apt install alsa-tools-gui` on my terminal.
2. Then I ran the command `hdajackretask` on my terminal.
3. Then selected Conexant CX20590 -- Red Mic--> Tick Override; from the dropdown select Microphone.
4. Then selected "Install Boot override" and entered sudo password.
5. I then restarted my pc and thankfully it worked !!
   [image: My config on hdajackretask]
6. Also, I remember adding the line "options snd-hda-intel model=laptop" to the file "/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf" .

Comment: worked for me, thanks a lot!

Comment: Worked for me, thanks a lot! But I had to check "Show unconnected pins" first, and try all of them one by one. Additionally, have found similar instructions on YouTube - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yx33W-c4Cmg

Answer (score 3):

My laptop is ACER E5-573G-74Q5. My codec is Realtek ALC255.

I did [Yurii S](https://askubuntu.com/a/1233446/586845)’s solution, but it didn’t work. Then [Soundar](https://askubuntu.com/a/1265295/586845) gave me the idea of putting more than one codec in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`, where I added the following line:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=alc255-acer,dell-headset-multi
```

Putting just one or the other didn't work, but putting both worked. Strange, but putting Dell codec on my Acer worked.

Comment: It worked for me too (acer swift SF 314-42), but sound from mic is pretty low quality with lots of background noise. Moreover, I cannot register and play the sound correctly on Audacity :/

Answer (score 2):

I have Dell Inspiron E7250 with PopOS 20.04 installed. I had same problem and it got resolved after adding following lines to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and rebooting.

```
options snd-hda-intel position fix=1
options snd-hda-intel index=0 model=dell-headset-multi,dell-e7x
```

Following is codec available in laptop

```
# cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: Intel Broadwell HDMI
Codec: Realtek ALC3235
```

Comment: Please, @soundar, where have you found out exact model to put into `alsa-base.conf`? I'd like to try your solution.... I have this `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ALC295
Codec: Intel Icelake HDMI` -

Comment: This worked perfectly for me after trying other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Install the `alsa-tools-gui` package:

```
sudo apt install alsa-tools-gui
```

Then run:

```
hdajackretask
```

Select the appropriate sound card up top in **Select a codec**, then make the **Black Mic (headphone jack)** *override*, and set to **Not connected**

In the lower right corner, select **Install boot override**.

Reboot and pray.

(Worked for me.)

Comment: nope, broke the audio, too.

Comment: Thank you! this works.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is to a question provided via a separate user's bounty of this question. As the question will disappear along with the bounty, I will include it, word for word, below, in hopes that it can be somewhat useful to users in the future.

> On my computer, the microphone sound is correctly detected in pavucontrol, but it's marked as unplugged and not present in audio parameters. I tried this: wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/… but Alsamixer interface is obscure. Provided answers do not fix my issue. Any hing how to progress on this? What's the respective roles of pulseaudio, pavucontrol, alsamixer?
>
> -Eric Burel

As for the answer,

I do not believe that alsa is your problem. Alsa is a driver database (among other things) whose job it is to connect your hardware with the proper "sound card" which actually refers to, again, a driver that provides access to that hardware (the physical sound card for which the alsa "sound card" is an abstraction.) It is more or less responsible for getting your hardware properly mapped into udev. As I said, there are other features, i.e the ins / outs, etc., but these mostly facilitate the main duties listed above.

You can check `pactl list cards` to be sure, but I guarantee that your device is linked to a driver. Otherwise Pulseaudio would not be detecting it. This doesn't mean that it is the correct driver. You can google

```
<MAKE> <MODEL> Alsa driver
```

getting the first two from your specs, and the first few results should contain something (at least close to) official from launchpad, linux-hardware.com, etc. From there, check the link for a driver. It may be called an "audio card", "Device Driver", or similar. Once you find the recommended, check that against the results of `lsmod | grep Audio`. If this command gives the name of your headphones in its output then don't worry about Google. You're good.

Alternatively, when you run the command that I included in my comment, or the one from above look through the names of all the `device.\*` entries. Once again, if you see your device model name, you're good.

Now for `pulseaudio`. Since you have nowhere to post command line output, I will recommend 2 `pulseaudio` gui packages that will get you up and running.

The first is `paprefs`. This is short for Pulseaudio Preferences. This app will let you configure pa streams.

Think of a stream as a pipe, but for sound. Your mic will ideally stream audio from `Alsa` (Source) into the stream (Source-Input) and at the other end of the stream (Sink-Input) it will feed into its output / destination (Sink, e.g. `Audacity` or another audio / streaming app.)

The Four main words in parentheses above are the keywords that make up the entire `pulseaudio` abstraction. If you know what these are, you can configure `pulseaudio` from pretty much any CLI or GUI.

`paprefs` lets you configure streams with actions such as moving them from one sink to another, etc. In your case , (although it is hard to tell without any console output) it sounds like you may have a stream without a sink.

The other app is `padevchooser`. This app doesn't really help in the current situation, but it does give extra capabilities to `pulseaudio`. It mostly focuses on sharing streams over the internal network.

If you would rather work with the command line, you can use `pacmd` or `pactl`. Both of these use the same objects that I described above. `pactl` is supposed to be a front-end for `pacmd`, but in my experience, they are pretty much the same save for slightly different syntax and the fact that `pacmd` can do a few things that `pactl` cannot.

If you can provide a venue to post the output to `pactl list cards`, `pactl list sources`, and `pactl list sink-inputs`, I can walk you through the process. However, without a way to tell what the issue is, I can only give you the tools.

`man pactl` and `man pacmd` will have all of the commands you need. These commands are well named, so you will know what each does immediately. Not much reading involved.

Comment: @EricBurel answer added. Let me know if you have any questions. If `pactl list sources` has a source for your mic, then your issue is not alsa.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the synthetic explanation. I'll trigger the bounty before it expires if there is no other answer, because a better understanding of what happens helps greatly.

Comment: You can always start a chat room to use for troubleshooting. If I could see command output, I could most likely gife you exact instructions as to how to fix it. You cn run `pactl list *` where * represents the four terms above. run in this order: `sources source-outputs sink-inputs sinks`. This is the flow of the signal. Find out where it stops, where the device is first missing from output. That is why I wanted to see the output. let me know the result.

Comment: Device is listed in `sources`, in `sinks`, but `source-outputs` and `sink-inputs` are empty. We might follow up on this link: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/issues/941 this is the issue I've opened directly in Pulse Audio ticket tracker, because there is certainly a bug somewhere (though I cannot tell yet if Pulse Audio is directly responsible or can provide a fix even if the bug is somewhere else).
Right now, I've bought a 10€ jack to USB C converter from a famous fruit-named brand to bypass the issue, works perfect.

Comment: At least it works now. Thanks for the link. Ill keep my eye on the issue, as I am interested in hearing the response from pa devs. Hopefully it will contain info that I can apply to helping people here. Let me know if /when you get a response, in case I miss it.

Answer (score 0):

When I came to this question (and similar other ones), the fix was rather simple:

1. Go to the "Sound Setting"
2. Click on the tab "Hardware"
3. Select the Profile "Analog Stereo Duplex" (it was "Analog Stereo Output" before").

Done.

[image]

Comment: that's not how the sound preferences in Ubuntu 20.04 look