# How to fix 3.5 mm audio jack not working after upgrading to 20.04

Tags: sound, 20.04, audio-jack

I tried Ubuntu Vanila, Mate and Kylin (all same version 20.04) still the same. It plays fine with the inbuilt speakers but when a headphone is plugged in there is no audio. In the speaker settings it changes from speaker to headphones but doesn't play. Then reinstalled 19.10 and now audio is fine.

Comment: This one worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230016/headset-microphone-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: I had the same problem, and this worked for me:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230016/headset-microphone-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04 Hope you have your headphones working.

Answer (score 8):

Try in your terminal

- `sudo apt update && sudo apt install alsamixer`
- run `alsamixer` in your terminal.
- press arrow right til you go to HEADPHONES bar.
- press `M` to unmute.
- press up/down to adjust the volume.
- press Esc to exit alsamixer.
- run `sudo alsactl store` in your terminal to store your settings earlier.

Comment: There is no headphones bar in alsamixer, only master and capture.

Comment: For me, this fixes it temporarily, but then unplugging and reinserting the 3.5mm speaker it stops working again

Comment: I can get it to work again by changing the profile for "Built-in Audio", cycling from
Analog Stereo Input > Analog Stereo Output > Analog Stereo Duplex, and then it works

Comment: It still is not working :(

Comment: It worked and the headphone is working but the sound is coming from the laptop's speaker also along with the audio. Please help

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu, headphone not muted in 'alsamixer', volume is high, still now sound!

Please try this, if your Ubuntu is using `snd hda intel`.

1. Open Terminal
   (*If you don't know where Terminal is, click Show Application in Unity, type Terminal, it should appear, click it open.*)
2. In Terminal type the command, **sudo nautilus**. Give your password as asked.
   This should have opened your file browser with access to root filesystem.
   Look for **etc** folder.
3. Inside **etc** folder, find **modprob.d** folder.
4. In **modprobe.d** find the file **alsa-base.cof** (or **alsa.conf** instead, if **alsa-base.conf** is not there.)
5. Copy the following two lines and paste as the last two lines in alsa configuration file you have just opened.

> ```
> options snd-hda-intel model=headset-mode
> options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi
> ```

6. Click 'Save' in alsa or alsa-base.
7. Restart the system. Plugin your headphone, microphone.

Now Ubuntu should be able to auto-detect headphone and microphone.

Comment: Great! This is what helped me get my sound working.

Answer (score 2):

Use `pavucontrol` and enable the microphone audio (and speaker). If the microphone is disabled the speaker doesn't work.

I don't know why this happens, but the above fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks! Unmuting the microphone in Input Devices worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still having problems, this worked for me as well as alot of people with "gaming" laptops: [link][1]

Pasting the answer that worked for me

so after having this issue with beautiful, but already annoying 20.04 I've found a solution in another post at superuser. In my case what helped me was:

```
cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec
```

to get the Audio Codec for your machine model.
In my case I saw Audio (ex: Codec: Realtek ALC233) & Video (ex: Codec Nvidia GPU 94 HDMI/DP) codecs there.

Go to [www.kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org) and look up the version of the codec, and get the full name of it. In my case: Realtek ALC233 -> alc233

Create/update a file under /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf, and add this line:
options snd-hda-intel model=alc233-eapd

while replacing model with yours

Reboot the machine.

It helped me, so let me know if that works for you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

20.04 headphones didn't work for me either. BUT after I finished doing another partial upgrade of packages evertyhing worked. Apparently something was missing / upgrade was not completely finished. Now headphones works just like 19.04.

Comment: After installing 20.04, I've updated the OS and rebooted but still the headphone jack is not working. Any particular package did you install?

Answer (score 0):

After installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my new Dell Vostro 3490 (2019) my 3.5 mm audio jack was not working. This is what worked for me:

1. Make sure *Headphones built-in audio* is selected in Ubuntu's *Sound Settings* in the *Output* panel.
2. Run alsamixer to unmute the headphone audio (as in @tanhernandez answer):

```
# alsamixer
```

3. Save alsamixer settings:

```
# sudo alsactl store
```

4. Run:

```
# lsactl restore
```