# Ubuntu 20.04 does not recognize headset microphone

Tags: sound, 20.04, alsa, microphone, headset

I have an Acer E5-574-307M notebook and I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed but it cannot recognize my headset microphone (Xiaomi Piston 3).

I searched the internet and found these possible solutions:

1. Edit the file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and add this command to the last line: `options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi`. However, it didn't work!
2. `rm -rf ~/.config/pulse/` and then restart the pc. However, it didn't work!
3. Use `cat /proc/asound/card0/codec# | grep Codec` to find out what the audio codec is and enter in this website to find out what the configuration is (alc255-acer, in my case). After knowing the configuration, enter the command: `options snd-hda-intel model=alc255-acer` in the file: `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and restart the PC. However, it didn't work!

P.S: This notebook only has one P2 input for the phone and microphone.

Answer (score 1):

This question is possible to duplicate of the question from here -> [Headset microphone not working on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230016/headset-microphone-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04)
If not, try these steps:

- Go to https://superuser.com/questions/1312970/headset-microphone-not-detected-by-pulse-und-alsa and try the steps mentioned in the first/second answer.
- Try installing multimedia extras plugin: `sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras`
  If problem persists, try reinstalling PulseAudio and other audio drivers
  I hope this solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following commands in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`.

```
options snd-hda-intel model=alc255-acer
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
```

Now, reboot.

This will disable the internal mic and detect the external headset mic.

This worked on **Acer Aspire 5 A514-54**.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my lenovo ideapad 135

I have added below lines to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

```
 options snd-hda-intel model=headset-mode  
 options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi
```

**Reboot** your system once after adding above lines