# Bluetooth headset problem - Ubuntu 20.04 Intel NUC10i5FNH4: When switching to HSP, receiving single error tone, then no audio output and no mic input

Tags: sound, 20.04, bluetooth, pulseaudio, microphone

I'm a recent migrant to Ubuntu 20.04 on an Intel Nuc10i5FNH4. I've had a great time for the most part - Ubuntu is so much better than windows for my needs.

However, a persistent issue has been that my bluetooth headset (Bose 700 Series headphones) will not work in HSP/HFP mode, meaning that I cannot use the microphone which I purchased it for. It works perfectly in a2dp mode, of course this mode will not permit microphone use.

When switching to HSP/HFP (using either bluetooth manager or ubuntu settings/bluetooth), I am met with a single error tone through the earphones.

Ubuntu settings/bluetooth, bluetooth manager and pavucontrol all suggest that the headphones are connected in HSP, but none of the above registers any audio picked up by my microphone, and no audio input/output works properly, other than the single error tone when first attempting to switch to HSP.

I have seen a number of other threads with similar kinds of issues, but none of them precisely seems to reflect what I have experienced and none of the solutions in those threads have helped me. As such, I've posted this in the hopes that someone can advise of where things may have gone wrong?

When I look at /lib/firmware/intel/ I can see that ibt-12-16.sfi is present, which I understand to be the firmware required for my NUC's intel bt chipset.

When using pacmd, I notice the following:

```
profiles: 
headset_head_unit: Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP) (priority 30, available: unknown)
```

Similarly, when looking at my syslog, I note the following error upon switching to HSP/HFP:

```
bluetoothd[1022]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
```

Admittedly, I am quite new to linux, so please be gentle. If there is any additional detail that I should provide, please don't hesitate to let me know.

Thanks so much to each of you for any assistance the community may be able to offer!

Comment: It's a bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1871794

Comment: Thanks so much for providing this information, Tineo. Much appreciated. Tell me, do you know if there are any other Linux distros which support usage of HSP/HFP for bluetooth headsets? If Ubuntu isn't fit for the purpose, it might just be time for me to switch to something else.

Comment: @newish2linux so how did you resolve your problem?