# Microphone randomly muting since Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, pulseaudio, lenovo, alsa, microphone

I recently upgraded my laptop (Lenovo ideapad 700-15ISK) from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04.

Since then, the microphone can randomly switch from activated to muted for no reason, changing its state every second during one or two minutes. It is getting very frustrating because the gnome notification in the middle of the screen is persistent during this lapse of time (switching from [activated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUNXg.png) to [muted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQCkJ.png)). It happens at least once a day. Apart from this weird behavior, the microphone works properly.

Reinstalling alsa and pulseaudio didn't fix the issue. Any ideas on this?

**Edit**

I reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 wiping everything with it. I'm still having the issue.

A temporary fix (when I'm not using the microphone) is to move the popup notification on the side of the screen with [Better OSD](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1345/better-osd/) extension.

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem, but it's with a *Bluetooth* microphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying out many things, I finally found the solution on another [topic](https://askubuntu.com/a/1233446/1047689).

I needed to had this line to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=alc233-eapd
```

where "alc233-eapd" is the audio codec reported in [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/hd-audio/models.html) for my machine.

Use `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec` to get your codec and look for the exact name in kernel.org.

Worked like a charm after a reboot!