# Ubuntu 20.04: Headphone Microphone is NOT detected

Tags: 20.04, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, headphones

I know this question has been asked already, but I have tried almost all the provided answers without being able to solve the problem.

I tried connecting a headset via bluetooth and a jack cable as well as connecting an earphone with all having a built-in Mic under Ubuntu 20.04. Only the output (which is the sound) is being detected each time, however, the input (the headset built-in Mic) is never detected and I don't have any give options. I didn't have this problem under Windows and Ubuntu 18.04 before, but only had it after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04.

I have tried already the following:

1. all the listed answers in [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230016/headset-microphone-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04?newreg=f4e92f5455c94b9394b609ff9ab6b64c)
2. [the troubleshooting of PulseAudio](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Microphone_not_detected_by_PulseAudio)
3. Updating to the latest kernel (5.9.4-050904-generic)
4. Different headsets and earphones (bluetooth and jacks)

The output of `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec` is the following:

```
Codec: Realtek ALC887-VD
Codec: Nvidia GPU 91 HDMI/DP
```

It is becoming frustrating now that I can't use an input Mic of headphones. In case it helps, this is the output of my `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`:

```
 autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
```

I attached a screenshot of [hdajackretask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOPV4.png), where I also tried to override `Green Headphone, Front side` which I am using for the connection and troubleshooting.

I appreciate any answer given for solving this problem. Thanks!!