# Choosing Headset in Select Audio Device doesn't set input device

Tags: sound, alsa, microphone

#### Problem

Whenever I plug in my headset, I get a *Select Audio Device* popup:

[image: Select Audio Device popup]

Naturally, I click *Headset*. Unfortunately, when I go to GNOME sound settings, I see that *Input Device* is unset. I have to then manually set it to *Headset Microphone - Built-in Audio*.

So my current workflow looks like:

1. Plug in headset
2. When popup shows click *Sound Settings*
3. Manually set *Input Device* to *Headset Microphone - Built-in Audio*

Shouldn't selecting Headset automatically set the input device? Isn't that the point of the popup? Why isn't it working?

#### Background

Out of the box, the output device in GNOME sound settings is listed as Coffee Lake something or other. It works in 20.04 but the headset microphone isn't detected.

In 18.04 the audio didn't work at all, which required me to use this workaround in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf (from https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem-osp1/+bug/1864061):

```
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
```

The headset microphone still doesn't seem to be detected, but at least the output device has a more understandable name ("Headphones - Built-in Audio").

I found another workaround in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf (from https://askubuntu.com/a/1233446/18665):

```
options snd-hda-intel model=alc233-eapd
```

Now with those two options set I get the aforementioned popup and my headset mic at least shows up as an option to select as an input device.