# Headset microphone not working on Ubuntu 20.10 with Realtek ALC289 codec

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, realtek, pavucontrol

My headset speakers work perfectly when connected to laptop with a TRRS AUX cable. The microphone is detected but doesn't work. However, the laptop's internal microphone works perfectly well.

AlsaInfo: http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=96ec47301fa1b125fe19dbb13fbafd21540ff6e7

I have tried most of the suggested fixes listed [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure). When following the steps in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1233446/1166712) answer, I found that the codec for ALC289 is missing from kernel.org. I have a feeling that I might have to install support for the codec from external sources. But that seems far fetched.

If someone has more experience with such situations, please help me out. I will be happy to provide more system info or logs.

Answer (score 1):

Also not working for me either, though it DID work when I first had Ubuntu installed. After upgrading bluetooth drivers and maybe installing some other sound packages, it stopped working. Input shows, and very tiny pickup of static noise, but nothing else.

Comment: I am having the same issue! It used to work, then I messed with trying to pair some bluetooth stuff, or some system updates came in, and it stopped working. Hopefully it'll be fixed in another system update at some point.