# how to report problem on ubuntu Wiki page? why there is lightdm and not gdm?

Tags: lightdm, gdm, ubuntu-wiki

I wanted to ask why is there (here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) in Step 1 `lightdm` package installed? I believe Ubuntu does not use `lightdm` but `gdm`, right?

I cannot modify the page or ask there, so I am asking here...

BTW, and no, following the whole step1 did NOT resolved the [microphone-not-working problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305942/wire-cable-external-headset-combo-jack-microphone-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-10) :(

Comment: I think it'll depend which release you're using... eg, *Xenial* still uses `lightdm` (see https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-desktop)  ... I'm looking at the page.

Comment: Page has been changed (it needs review before it's public)   Thank you @crysman   (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure?action=info)

Comment: I am on 20.10 Groovy, thanks for quick response

Comment: This question as I read it was about the wiki page, If you'd like to write an answer for it (*it was resolved as a result of your question here*) you're most welcome to (FYI: Ubuntu wiki, including help.ubuntu.com/community pages can be changed by anyone on the Wiki Editors Team https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wiki-editors).  Your sound issue should be asked in a different question.

Comment: It is being asked in different question, here is just a hyperlink as you may see...