# Computer doesn't recognize mic on my headset on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 recently from 18.04 and hard a hard time getting the computer to emit sound from the internal speakers, now i need to get it to register the microphone on my headset in order to speak in it.

Info i have:

It does detect the sound coming in the internal microphone, but it sounds like an airport.
My computer is an Acer Aspire 7741ZG
When typing cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* in the command line, it returns:

```
Codec: Realtek ALC272X
Codec: ATI R6xx HDMI
```

I tried methods from [Headset microphone not working on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230016/headset-microphone-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04) and got stuck when i needed to add the line to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

```
options snd-hda-intel model=???
```

I couldn't get the proper model of my chipset as it is not on this site https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/hd-audio/models.html
which bothers me is that i don't know where else to get it ?

Thanks for your help, have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer on https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=286654 where the guy just put auto in place of the chipset's name, thus my last line in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf is

```
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

Now i can talk in class !!!