# When changing the input device, no sound comes from the headphones in Ubuntu 20

Tags: 20.04, sound, microphone, headphones

I have some problems setting up the audio of my computer with my headset.
After first installing 20.04, I had no input/output of any kind through the jack connectors. After following some advice from other posts (https://askubuntu.com/a/1233446), I got the output and input audio to work, but not both at the same time.

The funny bit is that **the headset's microphone is available (and works fine) as an input device, but when I select it, the output device (headphones) stops working** (it is still displayed as selected and un-muted, but no sound comes from it). If I change the input device back to the internal microphone, the sound comes again through the headphones.

[View of the system settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f3YR.png)

System:

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- Sound card: Realtek ALC298

What have I tried:

- Uninstall and re-install alsa.
- Use different drivers for my sound card (there are several for the 298)
- Use different headphones and mic, including using a jack splitter for the input/output signals, with the same behavior.
- Use pavucontrol and alsa-mixer to check that none of the devices are muted.

Any suggestions on how to fix it or narrow down the issue?

Thanks.