# Mic on Headset doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I am trying to use a Jabra 40 Evolve Mono Headset on a Lenovo Thinkpad E490 running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. The headset comes with a 3.5mm jack and an 3.5mm-to-USB adapter. After finding [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230016/headset-microphone-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04), I tried out several things that highly upvoted answer suggested, but to no avail. In particular, I edited `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and added the line

`options snd-hda-intel model=auto`

since I couldn't find the drivers on kernel.org. Now the behaviour is as follows:

When I plug it in the 3.5mm jack, the output works fine but the microphone is not detected.

When I plug it in through USB, output works and the microphone *is* detected, however when I go to settings/sound and try to test it, no signal is detected in the input section. However, weirdly, when I'm speaking I'm getting some signals in the *output* section:

[image]
Note that I get this result by speaking, without any music or sound playing.

Comment: Is the "multichannel input" the only (Jabra named) input listed? What you called "3.5mm-to-USB adapter" is actually the other way around and not really an adapter. It's a full-featured external USB generic audio device (available at AliExpress for ~$1), an additional sound card. As such, depending on the chipset, it may show different inputs/outputs but only a couple will be usable.

Comment: @ChanganAuto there is another input which is named "Microphone - Jabra EVOLVE LINK". With that I don't get any result.