# mic from headset combo still shows plugged in after I unplugged it

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

The problem with that is it wont accept another mic input from my 3.5mm audio jack.
The speakers from same headset works as expected. When plugged in the output is switched to headset automatically and when unplugged the output switch back to laptop speakers. (Ubuntu 20.04)

I have been around the web and tried all suggestions from [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230016/headset-microphone-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04)

the output from `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec`

```
Codec: Nvidia GPU 9f HDMI/DP     Codec: Realtek ALC287    Codec: Intel Alderlake-P HDMI
```

Now the headset worked, mic just stopped working. It does work on my other laptop with UBUNTU 20.04