# Microphone not working properly on Lenovo Ideapad Flex 5 (14ALC05)

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, lenovo, microphone, ideapad

I have Ubuntu 23.04 installed on my Flex 5 and don't get any useful microphone output (see [this recording](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17jRMYvniWGhTZL0m8VYiYRQano7DrjML/view?usp=drivesdk)).
I tried using `pavucontrol` and also edited `alsa` and `pulseaudio` files (like described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230016/headset-microphone-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04)) but nothing seemed to change anything except for muting the output completely. Does anybody have any solution for this?
Output of `inxi -Fxz`:

```
System:
  Kernel: 6.2.0-24-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: GNOME
    v: 44.2 Distro: Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar Lobster)
Machine:
  Type: Convertible System: LENOVO product: 82HU v: IdeaPad Flex 5 14ALC05
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: LENOVO model: LNVNB161216 v: SDK0J40700 WIN
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI: LENOVO v: GJCN30WW date: 12/13/2022
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 39.8 Wh (87.9%) condition: 45.3/52.6 Wh (86.0%)
    volts: 13.0 min: 11.5 model: Sunwoda L19D3PD6 status: charging
  Device-1: wacom_battery_0 model: Wacom HID 5214 charge: 0% status: N/A
CPU:
  Info: 6-core model: AMD Ryzen 5 5500U with Radeon Graphics bits: 64
    type: MT MCP arch: Zen 2 rev: 1 cache: L1: 384 KiB L2: 3 MiB L3: 8 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1459 high: 2100 min/max: 1400/4056 boost: enabled cores:
    1: 1400 2: 1400 3: 1400 4: 1400 5: 1397 6: 2100 7: 1397 8: 1400 9: 1414
    10: 1400 11: 1400 12: 1400 bogomips: 50302
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Lucienne vendor: Lenovo driver: amdgpu v: kernel arch: GCN-5
    bus-ID: 04:00.0 temp: 49.0 C
  Device-2: Acer Integrated Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo bus-ID: 1-4:3
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.8 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.8
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: dri: radeonsi gpu: amdgpu
    resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 Mesa 23.0.2 renderer: AMD Radeon Graphics (renoir LLVM
    15.0.7 DRM 3.49 6.2.0-24-generic) direct-render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
    v: kernel bus-ID: 04:00.1
  Device-2: AMD ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor vendor: Lenovo driver: N/A
    bus-ID: 04:00.5
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h/19h HD Audio vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel
    v: kernel bus-ID: 04:00.6
  Sound API: ALSA v: k6.2.0-24-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-1: PulseAudio v: 16.1 running: no
  Sound Server-2: PipeWire v: 0.3.65 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8852AE 802.11ax PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    vendor: Lenovo driver: rtw89_8852ae v: kernel port: 2000 bus-ID: 02:00.0
  IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: <filter>
  Device-2: ASIX AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet type: USB driver: ax88179_178a
    bus-ID: 4-2:2
  IF: enxa0cec85b4e56 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Realtek Bluetooth Radio type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8
    bus-ID: 3-4:3
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 2 state: up address: <filter> bt-v: 3.0
    lmp-v: 5.2
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 54.88 GiB (11.5%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Western Digital model: PC SN530
    SDBPMPZ-512G-1101 size: 476.94 GiB temp: 46.9 C
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 136.54 GiB used: 51.72 GiB (37.9%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p5
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 256 MiB used: 38.7 MiB (15.1%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  Alert: No swap data was found.
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 54.2 C mobo: N/A gpu: amdgpu temp: 48.0 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Info:
  Processes: 361 Uptime: 35m Memory: 7.09 GiB used: 5.98 GiB (84.2%)
  Init: systemd target: graphical (5) Compilers: gcc: 12.2.0 clang: 15.0.7
  Packages: 2745 Shell: Bash v: 5.2.15 inxi: 3.3.25
```