# microphone not working, laptop HP 255 on dual-boot ubuntu 23.10

Tags: sound, kernel, alsa, microphone

I've installed latest ubuntu next to windows. Everything is working except the integral laptop microphone. It is not detected in settings.
I tried using [hdajackretask](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230016/headset-microphone-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04) and the mic did appear in settings but was not picking up any sound.

Looking at my codec, it is Realtek ALC236

I saw [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230016/headset-microphone-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04) it is suggested to find the whole name of the codec at [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/hd-audio/models.html) page and then add `options snd-hda-intel model=[name of the codec]` into `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

But I see that my codec is not present on the kernel.org. Is it then possible perhaps that it will come with future updates? My kernel is 6.5.7-060507-generic

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and the I restarted the pulseaudio daemon with

```
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio
```

and that worked for me.
You can also try out this steps from
[this article](https://support.system76.com/articles/audio/)