# My Ubuntu system can't detect audio devices

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hp, microphone

I am using Ubuntu on HP EliteBook g3 840. My system can't detect any audio device including the internal speakers and mics.

[image: Image of No output devices detected]

I have checked my BIOS and everything is OK. I checked system logs with `journalctl -xe | grep -i pipewire` for additional info and I got this.

```
Dec 06 12:12:49 victor-HP-EliteBook-840-G3 pipewire-pulse[8367]: mod.protocol-pulse: 0x55fb904c1850: failed to connect client: Host is down
Dec 06 12:12:49 victor-HP-EliteBook-840-G3 pipewire-pulse[8367]: mod.protocol-pulse: client 0x55fb904cf7b0 [GNOME Shell Volume Control]: ERROR command:9 (SET_CLIENT_NAME) tag:1 error:6 (Host is down)
```

Comment: Does this work for you?  https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues/2339#issuecomment-1722878951

Comment: I have a similar problem ([here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1495095/microphone-not-working-laptop-hp-255-on-dual-boot-ubuntu-23-10?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C0.0000)) and this solution did not work for me.

Comment: @nobody I followed the issue and I later understood and found a solution. Thanks.

Comment: @zheppam try running `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio`